# jQuery function in TWIG layout doesn't work properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to create simple "admin" page for my blog. For now I want to create some "dynamic" behaviour which will lock/unlock user. Then I want to replace single table row with another, taken from json. I wrote a simple function but unfortunatelly it is not working properly...

When I use constant value for user id (just for tests) it works, but only for ONE row. Other buttons do nothig. Then I tried to send id to my function as a parameter but now it says it doesn't exist in my TWIG (what is true).

I want to make it work, because reloading all page when you only locked one user or did another single action, is not a good idea.

How can I make my function work in a good way?

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".LockUserButton").click(function(id){
            $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('locked progress-bar-striped');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{ path('lock_ajax', {'id': id }) }}",
                data: { user_id: "{{ user.id }}" },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('locked progress-bar-striped');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**TWIG**

```
<div class="table-content">
    {% for u in users %}
            {% if u.locked %}
                <tr id="tableRow" class="locked progress-bar-striped">
            {% else %}
                <tr id="tableRow" class="">
            {% endif %}

            {% if u.roles[0] == 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' %}

                <td id="roles">
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star admin-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ u.roles[0] }}"></span></h4>
                </td>
                <td>{{ u.username }}</td>
                <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock admin-lock" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Cannot modyfi this user!"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock admin-lock" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Cannot modyfi this user!"></span>
                </td>

            {% else %}

                <td id="roles">
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty user-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ u.roles[0] }}"></span></h4>
                </td>
                <td>{{ u.username }}</td>
                <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn btn-custom LockUserButton">LOCK USER WITHOUT RELOADING</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/profile/admin/delete_user/{{ u.id }}" onclick="return confirm('{{ 'user.deleting'|trans }}')">
                        <div class="btn btn-custom hvr-grow">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>

            {% endif %}

            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION**

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/ajax/{id}", name="lock_ajax")
 */
public function ajaxLock($id, Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);

    if($user->isLocked()){
        $user->setLocked(false);
    }else{
        $user->setLocked(true);
    }

    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $result = array();
    $result[0] = $user;

    return new JsonResponse($result);
}
```

Comment: At the very least you can add a `data` attribute for example to your `row` with current user's `id` which you can already access within your loop block and get the value in your jQuery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Artamiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763926/artamiel) I have finally figure it out! Here's the solition for my case:

1) I have added `data-id="{{ u.id }}"` attribute to my button. Now i have access to my entity ID.

2) I have modify a little my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".LockUserButton").click(function(){
            //get user id from twig layout
            var user = $(this).data("id");

            //ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/profile/ajax/"+user,
                data: { user_id: "user" },
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function () {
                    //i've wrote some function to toggle html
                    $(this).toggleText('{{ 'user.unlocked'|trans }}', '{{ 'user.locked'|trans }}');

                    //find table row and toggle classes when button clicked and request ok
                    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('locked progress-bar-striped');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```